# change password without current password field in php

Tags: php, mysql

In the Below code i have Current password, new password and repeat new password fields **but i don't want current password field to change password.**

**Note :** I want only new password and repeat new password in the form.

```
<?php
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
//user is logged in
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//start changing password
//check fields

$oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
$newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);


$repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

//check password against db
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

$queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM members WHERE username='$user'") or die ("change password failed");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
$oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

//check passwords
if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
{
//check two new passwords
if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
{
//successs
//change password in db

$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$user'");
session_destroy();
die("Your password has been changed. <a href='login.php'> Login Again</a>");
}
else 
die("New password doesn't match!");

}else 
die("Old password doesn't match!");

}
else
{

echo"
<form action='change_password.php' method='POST'>
Old Password: <input type='text' name='oldpassword'><p>
New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><p>
Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
<input type='submit' name ='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
";
 }
}else 
die ("You must be logged in to change your password");
?>
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/aKHLA3Q

Comment: remove the html input field of old password.

Comment: @Jenz its giving the following validation : Old password doesn't match!

Comment: remove lines #14, #23-#30, #43-#44, & #52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
     <?php
        session_start();

    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
    //user is logged in
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //start changing password
    //check fields

    $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);


    $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

    //check password against db
    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM members WHERE username='$user'") or die ("change password failed");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);


    //check two new passwords
    if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
    {
    //successs
    //change password in db

    $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$user'");
    session_destroy();
    die("Your password has been changed. <a href='login.php'> Login Again</a>");
    }
    else {
    die("New password doesn't match!");

    }
    else
    {

    echo"
    <form action='change_password.php' method='POST'>
    Old Password: <input type='text' name='oldpassword'><p>
    New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><p>
    Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
    <input type='submit' name ='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
    ";
     }
    }else 
    die ("You must be logged in to change your password");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove old password field from your form as well remove if condition which checks your old password in database with old password to form

here is code you may need

```
 <?php
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
//user is logged in
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//start changing password
//check fields
$newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);


$repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

//check password against db
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

$queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM members WHERE username='$user'") or die ("change password failed");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
$oldpassworddb = $row['password'];


//check two new passwords
if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
{
//successs
//change password in db

$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$user'");
session_destroy();
die("Your password has been changed. <a href='login.php'> Login Again</a>");
}
else 
die("New password doesn't match!");



}
else
{

echo"
<form action='change_password.php' method='POST'>
New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><p>
Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
<input type='submit' name ='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
";
 }
}else 
die ("You must be logged in to change your password");
?>
```

Comment: you should also remove `$oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);` as `$_POST['oldpassword']` will give a `Notice: undefined index oldpassword` since it is no longer in the form.